# Существуют ли команды для Windows, Mac OS, Linux, чтобы узнать действующие сетевые настройки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, сеть, macos

Пишу код на Python3. Одни из задач моей программы - это узнать MAC адрес и IP адрес.

Вопросы:

1. Если узнавать действующий IP адрес Windows, то я пользуюсь методом `gethostbyname()`, но с MAC адресом уже проблема. Единственный выход, который я нашел, это вызывать команду с помощью метода `check_output(['getmac', '/v', '/fo', 'list'])`(выходит список адаптеров с MAC адресами), но как вы знаете сетевых интерфейсов много (беспроводная сеть, проводная сеть и т.д.). Каким способом, методом получить именно тот MAC адрес, который работает в сети? Может есть специальный метод модуля subprocess или команда в cmd, похожий на метод `gethostbyname()`?
2. Ситуация с Mac OS и Linux сложнее. Если вбить в терминале ifconfig, то сетевых интерфейсов куча. Если брать в пример Mac OS, подключаешься к Wi-Fi - интерфейс: en0, подключаешься к проводной сети - интерфейс уже другой. Как узнать в ОС Mac OS и Linux действующие в сети IP адрес и MAC адрес?

Общий вопрос такой: Есть ли способы, методы узнавать в ОС Windows, Mac OS, Linux действующие IP адрес и MAC адрес (которые работают в сети, например Интернет).

Если я не точен в формулировке, простите. Я новичок.

Правка: Действующие в сети - я имею ввиду именно тот интерфейс, который в данный момент работает для подключения к Интернету или к локалке. Нужно узнать IP и MAC именно этого интерфейса.

Comment: Не вирус. Проект для моей компании. При решении проблемы в сети или в сервере, есть большая вероятность, что виноваты сами пользователи. Но они не умеют или не хотят вбивать в консоле или в терминале команды и говорить нам ip, mac, домен и хост.

Comment: Показывайте все IP/MACи. Потому как одновременно работающих интерфейсов может быть больше одного, и даже одновременно несколько может быть с доступом в Интернет.

Comment: На счет реализации для каждой ОС. Я так и и хочу сделать. Взять в пример бухгалтеров наших, у которых есть аж целых три сетевых карт(для определенных задач). Не важно какая ОС, проблема останется, что код не будет знать название всех интерфейсов. Тогда уж нужно писать код не под каждую ОС, а под каждый компьютер к сожалению.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Могу посоветовать обратить внимание на `psutil` и подметод [`net_if_addrs()`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.net_if_addrs):

```
import psutil
print(psutil.net_if_addrs())
```

Возвращает объект со всеми интерфейсами, включая их IP и MAC-адрес. Ну и работает везде.

Comment: Спасибо вам! Я не мог решить этот вопрос неделю. Теперь можно методом перебора найти нужные мне интерфейсы. Я теперь обожаю эту библиотеку.

Comment: Если вы знаете еще библиотеки (или модули, я еще плаваю в формулировках) по сетям, прошу Вас поделиться. Если не сложно)

Comment: @Bulat_Akhmadeev Не за что. Рад, что помогло. Библиотека для различного мониторинга очень удобно сделана. Если что-то еще вспомню, то обновлю пост и в коммент отпишусь.

Answer (score 0):

Ты можеш выяснить на какой системе ты запускаеш скрипт.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854/python-what-os-am-i-running-on

после этого ты можеш использовать модуль `subprocess` что бы запускате необходимую команду в терминале. Потом парсиш результаты и вуаля.

Пример для линукса, но можно подшаманить и для остальных ситем:

```py
import subprocess
from collections import namedtuple

CmdOutput = namedtuple("CmdOutput", ["output_lines", "output_string"])


def execute_sh(cmd: str, ) -> CmdOutput:
    cmd += " 2>&1"
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE
    stderr = subprocess.STDOUT
    p = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd, shell=True, executable="/bin/bash", stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr
    )
    lines = [line.decode('utf-8') for line in p.stdout.readlines()]
    string = "".join(lines)
    return CmdOutput(lines, string)
```